# Word "position" for map?

Tags: expressions

Can word Position be used to describe my location in the map/directory?

I often saw "You are here", "Here", and "Your Current location" signs, but haven't seen "Your Current Position" or "Present Position".

Will that still make sense and natural if I say "Your Current Position" or "Present Position"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use

> **Position**

it may sound very formal. It often gets used for navigation and is usually associated with the military where soldiers are often asked if they are in **position** to do something.

As a normal person driving along the road, you might say

> I'm **on** the highway just outside of town,  and I'll be there by 4 o'clock.

If you said

> My current position is heading south, south-west on highway 66 and I'll be there by 16:00 hours.

People will understand what you are saying, but ***how*** you are saying it might be made fun of, unless you were a professional pilot.

The other thing is **position** gets used to mean something totally different.
If someone said to you

> Assume the **position**.

It means they will probably give you a spanking.

If you asked someone of the opposite sex

> What is your position?

It may be interpreted as asking about your sexual preference.

Comment: Thank you, but will "Your Present Position" be fine when it is used for a sign as "Your current location" on a map?

Comment: You can use it, it would be understood, but it's not really done that way.